# RegEx to replace every sub-child node's Value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to use RegEx to replace a sub-child `T` node with `n="upper_bound"` for any occurrence of a parent `T` node with a `n="Key"` value of `32305` such that I can replace `<T n="upper_bound">10</T>` to `<T n="upper_bound">ANY_NEW_VALUE_HERE</T>`

I'd also prefer to leave the comments.

Example snippet of the XML format:

```
<U>
    <T n="key">32304<!--Key for Y--></T>
    <U n="value">
      <T n="upper_bound">20</T>
    </U>
</U>
<U>
    <T n="key">32305<!--Key for X--></T>
    <U n="value">
      <T n="upper_bound">10</T>
    </U>
</U>
```

Comment: Completely wrong path - use an `XML` parser in your preferred programming language instead, that's what they were made for.

Comment: I'm not using a programming language, I'm simply using notepad++ w/ regex. So are you saying it is impossible? It's not worth spinning up a whole project to edit these XMLs. I was just curious if I could do this for convenience's sake...

Answer (score 1):

Aparantly not the wrong path, as I was able to figure it out in two ways. I'm sure there is a more graceful way to do this, but it does the trick for my scope since I can make assumptions about the immediate parent node.

PCRE RegEx:

```
(<T n="key">32305<!--Key for X--><\/T>\n        <U n="value">\n          <T n="upper_bound">).*(<\/T>)
```

Substitution:

```
$1NEW_VALUE_HERE$2
```

It replaces the value between the two groups.

With NotePad++ RegEx, I can search for the entire hardcoded text, and, in my case, I can assume the value for the node I'm looking for is a 2-digit number

```
<T n="key">32305<!--Key for X--></T>
    <U n="value">
      <T n="upper_bound">\d\d</T>
```

Replace with:

```
<T n="key">32305<!--Key for X--></T>\n\t\t<U n="value">\n\t\t\t<T n="upper_bound">NEW_VALUE_HERE</T>
```

Hopefully this helps someone and I would be interested in other solutions, other than the quick dismissive comment I was greeted with.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you were not pleased by the quick dismissive you have suffered as a first reaction.

The reason why Jan was so short in his answer is probably that he didn't know at the moment you asked your question that you were speaking about a regex inside of NotePad++.

Since the right way to modify an XML file is not through regex, we get tired to repeat that to the developpers who visit SO. Sorry about that.

Now, for the case you want to modify the XML file including the snippet above with a script, the right path is:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
  --update '//U/T[@n="key" and text()="32305"]//following-sibling::U' \
  --value 'ANY_NEW_VALUE_HERE' input.xml
```

You will get the result you wanted as standard output. It is also possible to modify the file directly with the option `--inplace`.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. Looks like you are recommending Starlet, my limited understanding of this is it uses shell commands to modify XML files?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly. If you execute the command above, you will not modify your input XML file but you will get a new XML file as output, that you can save somewhere. If you add the option `--inplace` between `xmlstarlet` and `edit` in the command line above, you will see no output but the input file will be modified.